# OrbitControls rotating whole scene instead of object

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, orbitcontrols

I'm new to Three.js and have been trying to make this globe work, so that when you rotate it with the mouse it only rotates the globe and doesn't make the halo effect seen.

Could I solve it with OrbitControls or is there a workaround to make the halo turn with the camera?

This is the current code for OrbitControls:

```
const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, globe_el );
```

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/ninakos123/pen/GRdqqBb